# Radio button not selected when mouse-clicked?

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button

For some reason if I tab through my radio buttons (and use the arrow keys to select different ones) the current radio button is selected. I can tell because there's a blue highlight circle around it (Google Chrome). But if I click a radio button with the mouse, that blue circle is not there.

The problem is that I'm trying to create a smooth tab flow through my page. If the user uses nothing but tab and arrow keys, it works fine. If they use nothing but the mouse, it works fine, obviously (because tabIndex would be irrelevant). But if they click a radio button with the mouse, and then press tab, it fails. Specifically, it tabs to the first element on the page, rather than tabbing to the next element after the radio button. Any ideas?

Comment: What is this question about? I'm sorry if it's obvious, but I'm not really sure.

Comment: His trying to make sure the tab button on a keyboard affects decision on a user makes that can be used to select a radio button on a webpage as well as using the mouse click to do the same thing.

Comment: If the user mouse-clicks a radio button and then hits tab to move to the next element, it doesn't go to the next element, but instead it goes to the first element on the page. The reason why is because the radio button is not being highlighted by the mouse-click.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out. The word I was looking for was 'focus'. Mouse-clicking a radio button doesn't seem to give the button focus. It removes focus from any element, kind of like clicking in the background. My solution was to call a javascript function to the onclick event that assigns focus to the radio button using focus().

Answer (score 0):

It's obvious that the tabindex goes right to the first element it's commanded to.

Comment: I'm not understanding your answer. And I'm not necessarily talking about the first time you hit tab. You can tab through half the elements on the page, then click a radio button, then hit tab and it jumps back to the first element.

Comment: I think I figured it out. The word I was looking for was 'focus'. Mouse-clicking a radio button doesn't seem to give the button focus. It removes focus from any element, kind of like clicking in the background. My solution was to call a javascript function to the onclick event that assigns focus to the radio button using focus().